# Unresolved dependencies while trying to install passenger

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passenger, apt

I have a problem while trying to install passenger on apache2.

When I try to install it says:

```
passenger: depend: libruby1.8 (>= 1.8.7.357-1) but 1.8.7.352-2ubuntu1.3 is installed
```

I tried to update && upgrade, I removed, cleaned and reinstall the lib, and updated my source.list but nothing worked...

Here is my source.list:

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe
```

Here are the repositories that I use

`deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger lucid main`
`deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger precise main`
`deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger saucy main`
`deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger squeeze main`
`deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger wheezy main`

Comment: Which repository are you using? The official Phusion repository's Precise packages depend on libruby1.8 (>= 1.8.7.352).

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what was wrong, I only needed to use the precise repository.

`deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger precise main`